# Floating Action Button XML in Compose Project not showing correctly

Tags: xml, android-jetpack-compose, floating-action-button

I'm trying to combine XML and Compose in one project, here is my FAB:

```
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rew"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_shopping_cart_24"  />
```

I also added those two dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0' 
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
```

Here is what the preview looks like:
[image]

The same code in a newly created Kotlin + XML project works just fine and it displays a circle FAB.
But in a Jetpack Compose Project it looks square and grey.
Most of my App is written in Compose but I have one dialog which is written in XML so I want to display a XML FAB in there.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing my parent theme in my themes.xml file from

```
parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"
```

to

```
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"
```